# Converting a date to its Julian number

Tags: c++, date, julian-date

I want to calculate difference between two dates, time and secs, and I know atleast for dates converting it to two Julian Numbers and subtracting it is an efficient way.
I am trying to implement [this](https://alcor.concordia.ca/~gpkatch/gdate-algorithm.html) algorithm for that. 
Below is my implementation for today i.e. *12-22-2015*

```
function g(y,m,d)
m = (m + 9) % 12
y = y - m/10
return 365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + (m*306 + 5)/10 + ( d - 1 )

function g(2015,12,22)
[9] m = (12 + 9) % 12
[2014.1] y = 2015 - 9/10

735146.5 + 503.525 + 20.141 + 5.03525 + 275.9 + 21
=**735954.10125**
```

However from [this](http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm) online calculation tool the correct value is: `2457378.877`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code doesn't look like C++.  Have you implemented it in javascript?  Note that your link says "all division is integer division", so y = 2015 - 9/10 should result in 2015, not 2014.1.

Comment: i didn't copied the code but just the calculation steps. why 2015, should be 2014 if we round 2014.1 off to floor?

Comment: No.  The calculation needs to go 2015 - 9/10 => 2015 - 0 => 2015.  The division 9/10 rounds towards zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that the algorithm you use has a value of 1 around the start of 1AD.  Julian dates start in 4713BC.

For your purposes that may not matter, (but it makes it harder to check online).  Excel is good at comparing time points after the start of the 20th Century.  If you actually want to convert to Julian date, you will need to search for the algorithm.  For example: https://gist.github.com/jiffyclub/1294443  is suitable code in python - you will need to convert to your language of choice